# How to add double click listener to primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

What i want to do is; when user clicks to row, it will select the row.When user double clicks to row, it will start cell editing. At Primefaces showcase(http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/d ... nstant.jsf) it says "Instant row selection, dblclick selection and unselection is implemented using ajax behaviors." but i couldnt find where they implemented dblclick selection. Is there a way to start cell editing event with double click event?

Answer (score 21):

```
<p:ajax event="rowDblselect">
```

From  [PrimeFaces Users Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html)

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Use

```
<p:ajax event="rowDblselect" />
```

in your `<p:dataTable />` like this:

```
<p:dataTable 
    id="yourTableId" 
    value="#{yourBean.items}" 
    selectionMode="single" 
    selection="#{yourBean.selectedItem}" 
    var="item" 
    rowKey="#{item.id}">

    <p:ajax 
        event="rowDblselect" 
        listener="#{yourBean.onRowDoubleClick}" 
        update="@form:theComponentYouWantToUpdate" 
        global="false" />

    <!-- your columns here -->

</p:dataTable>
```

In your bean/controller use:

```
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;

public void onRowDoubleClick(final SelectEvent event) {
    YourObject obj = (YourObject) event.getObject();
    // rest of your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `dblClickSelect="true"` on your table.

From the documentation:

> By default, row based selection is enabled by click event, enable dblClickSelect so that clicking  double on a row does the selection.

Comment: There is no "dblClickSelect" property at datatable. By the way i am using primefaces 3.5

Comment: Hmm... according to the [3.5 documentation](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf) there should be. See page 137. Still maybe there's a mistake. From what I remember this worked in v 2.